# The many-to-many relationship of Realm

Tags: many-to-many, realm, relationship

the relationship of user and group.

```
public class User extends RealmObject {
    public String uid;
    public String name;
    public RealmList<Group> groups;
}

public class Group extends RealmObject {
    public String gid;
    public String name;
    public RealmList<User> members;
}
```

But now, there's a role called 'creator' or 'administrator', which belongs to the relationship, neither User nor Group, how should I add the property to RealmObject?

Comment: I don't fully follow you, but do you mean that a `Group` have a creator and an administrator? If so, you can add properties like `User creator` to `Group`.